# Issue accessing state array from inside animationFrame with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, requestanimationframe

I am trying to update some elements on scroll by using animationFrame.  I want to add an easing effect so I would like the elements to update their positions by the eased value.  I figured the best way to do this would be to store all of the values in an array and update them accordingly.  When each element is mounted I am sending them to a context element that adds them to the state value array.

My issue is that I cannot access the array from inside the animating function. It is available outside of the animating function but not inside.  I am assuming that the animation is starting before the array is being populated but I have tried to stop and restart the animation when the blocks array changes with useEffect but to no avail.

Here is a codesandbox of the issue [Example Of Issue](https://codesandbox.io/s/scrolling-animation-frame-array-issue-o4n3m)

In the sandbox you can see in the `animate()` function in the ScrollContainer component I am console logging the `blocks` array and then after the function I am logging the same array.  When you scroll the array does not log the available blocks only an empty array.  But the available blocks are being logged correctly under this function.

```
const animate = () => {
  const diff = yScroll - yCurrent;
  const delta = Math.abs(diff) < 0.1 ? 0 : diff * ease;
  if (delta) {
    yCurrent += delta;
    yCurrent = parseFloat(yCurrent.toFixed(2));
    animationFrame = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  } else {
    cancelAnimation();
  }
  console.log("Animating Blocks", blocks);
};

console.log("Available Blocks", blocks);

const addBlock = block => {
  setBlocks(prev => {
    return [...prev, block];
  });
};
```

and here is how I am starting the animation

```
const startAnimation = () => {
  if (!animationFrame) {
    animationFrame = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  }
};

useEffect(() => startAnimation(), []);
```

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see in your example that you're using the `blocks` variable inside the `animate` function, but if that was the case, I'd use the `useEffect` hook, put the variables you care about inside of the dependency array, and do your calculations/whatever inside of that hook when any of those state variables change - otherwise you will be seeing "stale" data/state.

Comment: @goto1 You can see very clearly that I am logging the blocks to the console in the example inside the animate function. If you looked at the console you can see it logging.  And useEffect has no effect on the outcome I have tried restarting the animation, clearing and restarting, and reinitializing the entire thing when blocks changes I stated this in the question.  You can mess with the codesandbox and see that is why I made it.

Comment: I am looking at it right now, if you want to be able to access the latest state inside of the `animate` function you have to use a separate `useEffect` hook for that, otherwise you will keep getting stale data as is the case right now. You need to change that logic.

Comment: Is your goal to read the state of `blocks` or update it inside of `animate`?

Comment: @goto1 The goal is just to read the blocks state inside the animate function.  If I understand correctly I should be able to set the blocks state and then inside useEffect with blocks as a dependency restart the animation function and the animate function should be using the new state because the component should be re-rendered with the new state but that does not seem to be the case no matter what I do.

Comment: Ignore the stuff I did under that `CodeSandbox` example - it will not work, I was just trying to see some stuff and for some reason I can't fork your example. Have a look at this - https://css-tricks.com/using-requestanimationframe-with-react-hooks/ & https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14195 - I don't know how to fix this at the moment without playing with it myself.

Comment: You can change the codesandbox all you want it will not edit the original sandbox that is the point of the sandbox environment you can play with it as much as you like.

Comment: Right, I'd rather fork it and play with my own version otherwise I am messing up your  original example for someone else. For some reason I wasn't able to fork it when I tried but no big deal.

Comment: @goto1 you won't mess up the original sandbox example only I can edit or save the original example if you see changes its because it is cached to your browser.  Make a change and then open it in a private window and you can see the original is still the same.

Comment: @goto1 I found the issue is with the update scroll function.  I needed to reinitialize that function when blocks are added.

Comment: I don't think this is the way to go about this problem, but if you wanted to access latest state for `blocks` inside of `animate` you could use that `useRef` technique from that `css-tricks` article - https://codesandbox.io/s/scrolling-animation-frame-array-issue-u2jkz?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark - but I think there's a better way to go about this, would have to spend some more time on this though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I played with your example. It seems to me, that the problem is in the useEffect. If you add empty dependency to it, then it runs only once after the first render. There will be a second render when blocks state updates, but for the useEffect only the first state is visible because it runs only once and it uses the startAnimation with stale closure. This version of startAnimation uses the first version of the animation with the original state.

Your initial problem is solved if you add blocks to the useEffect as a dependency.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    yScroll = window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset;
    yCurrent = yScroll;
    startAnimation();

    window.addEventListener("scroll", updateScroll);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", updateScroll);
    };
  }, [blocks]);
```

I tried adding the animation, but is is quite choppy to me. I'm interested in your final solution. This is mime: https://codesandbox.io/s/scrolling-animation-frame-array-issue-d05wz

I use higher level animation libraries like react-spring. You can consider using something like this. I think it is much easier to use.

https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-water-sykyj

Comment: So I ended up just adding the blocks array to a ref this way just seems easier to me. Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve codesandbox.io/s/desktop-momentum-scrollingparallax-react-t8wr5. I put an explanation of it on the sandbox because it is too long to explain in the comments. If you think there is a more efficient way to go about this let me know. The reason I couldn't access the blocks state was because I needed to re initiate the updateScroll function when blocks were added I was trying to re initiate the animate function but the stale updateScroll fucntion was the problem.

Comment: I like your framework. I have no suggestion for more efficient solution. I might create a react-spring version for fun, but it will not be more efficient. It would be simpler at most and not terrible slower.